# Enviar email PHP e CPANEL - Autenticação de email

Tags: php, email, envio-de-email, cpanel

Qual a maneira mais correcta de enviar um email usando PHP. Sendo este email autenticado?

Answer (score 5):

Tive que aprender isto para implementar num projecto, não encontrei nenhum tutorial que explicasse tudo bem por isso deixo aqui o que fazer.

Se gostarem dêem upvote para mais pessoas verem.

Notas: 
1 - No código apenas podem colocar o sender a acabar em '@dominio_do_site.com'
2 - Serviços como Hotmail podem colocar os e-mails não devidamente autenticados na pasta do lixo.

Ao receber o Email enviado os serviços de email (gmail..) podem dar varios problemas:

Problema 1:
O Gmail, avisa o destinatário que não consegue verificar se o email foi realmente enviado pelo email especificado no 'sender'.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Solução:
Para não ter este "erro" tem de ir ao C-Panel ir a email>autenticação de email e activar tanto o DKIM como o SPF. Nesta parte se tiver algum problema, ao contactar o seu hosting service deve conseguir solução. Mas em principio é só clicar em dois botões.

Problema 2:
Ao lado do email especificado no código para aparecer no sender, pode aparecer o servidor de email que realmente mandou o email. Exemplo: "através de io.wv.pt"
Sendo o io.wv.pt o servidor de email, que varia dependendo da empresa que esta a fazer host ao website.

Solução:

No código é necessário utilizar headers e outros parâmetros e não apenas o básico.

Código:

```
<html><head>

<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<?php
$to = "email_envio@gmail.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! \nThis is a simple email message.";

$headers = "From: lalala@savemybananas.com";
$headers .= "\r\nReply-To: lalala@savemybananas.com";
$headers .= "\r\nX-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers,"-f lalala@savemybananas.com");

echo "Mail Sent.";
?> 


</html>
```

(gente editem a perguntem como quiserem em termos de formatação. Considero que o core esta bom)