# Formulário de Contato não envia mensagem - UOL Host

Tags: php, html, formulário

O formulário até pega os dados após clicarmos em submit, envia o usuário a uma página de agradecimento mas a mensagem não chega ao destino, que é meu e-mail.

**HTML**:

```
<section id="contato">                      
                <h1>CONTATO</h1>    
                    <div id="caixas-texto">
                        <form action="contato.php" method="post">
                            <label for="nome">Nome:</label> <br>
                            <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" size="48" maxlength="48"><br><br>
                            <label for="fone">Telefone:</label> <br>
                            <input type="text" id="fone" name="fone" size="11" maxlength="11"><br><br>
                            <label for="email">Email:</label> <br>
                            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" size="48" maxlength="48"><br><br>
                            <label for="msg">Mensagem:</label> <br>
                            <textarea id="msg" name="msg" rows="5" cols="50"maxlength="200"
                            placeholder="Mande sua mensagem! Vamos trabalhar!"></textarea>

                            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="bt_enviar">
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

**PHP**

```
        <?php
$para= "email@contato.com.br";
$assunto= "Contato pelo site";
$nome= $_REQUEST['nome'];
$fone= $_REQUEST['fone'];
$email= $_REQUEST['email'];
$mensagem= $_REQUEST['msg'];
    $corpo= "<strong> Mensagem de Contato</strong><br><br>";
    $corpo .= "<br><strong> Nome: </strong> $nome";
    $corpo .= "<br><strong> Telefone: </strong> $fone";
    $corpo .= "<br><strong> Email: </strong> $email";
    $corpo .= "<br><strong> Mensagem: </strong> $mensagem"; 
    $header= "Content-Type: text/html; charset= utf-8\n";
    $header .="From: $email Reply-to: $email\n";    
mail($para,$email,$assunto,$corpo,$header);
header("location:retorno-email.html?envio=enviado");
?>
```

Meu site está em um servidor do UOL, não entendo o que pode estar havendo.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Enviar email PHP e CPANEL - Autenticação de email](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119458/enviar-email-php-e-cpanel-autentica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-email)

Comment: Te recomendo usar algum servidor de envio de email com SMTP configurado certinho.
O próprio site da UOL tem um artigo sobre esse assunto: https://uolhost.uol.com.br/faq/v2/hospedagem/como-enviar-mensagens-com-php-por-autenticacao-smtp.html#rmcl Fazendo da forma como você mostrou, pode acontecer do email demorar muito para chegar, ou nem chegar por ser considerado spam de um remetente não confiável. Basicamente falando, te recomendo configurar o servidor do email da UOL para fazer esses envios pra você.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua solução. Ela me ajudou a resolver o problema. No endereço https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/5.2-stable eu pude encontrar uma versão com os arquivos que precisava para fazer o meu formulário funcionar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Deve da trocando a ordem também.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, já consegui fazer meu formulário funcionar!